# How do I call a global function in a vue.js child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The global function `init()` outputs a console log when the screen is loaded. However, clicking the child component button does not re-enable the `init()` function.

How can I call the global function `init()` when I click a button in my child's component?

App.vue (parent)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link :to="{name: 'home'}">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link :to="{name: 'about'}">About</router-link>
    </div>
     <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import './assets/css/style.css'
  import './assets/js/commmon.js'

  export default {
  }
</script>
```

Home.vue (child)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="btn_link">Home Button</a><br><br>
  </div>
</template>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import About from './views/About.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home},
    { path: '/about', name: 'about', component: About},
  ]
})

function init() {
  console.log('load inti()')
}
init();

$('#btn_link').click(function(){
  init();
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't. Don't use jQuery with modern frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of js modules is to stop you having, or supposedly needing, a global scope. People sometimes suggest a workaround of adding your global functions to the Vue object, which strikes me as a cure worse than the disease. My answer to this is to `provide` one global object in the root of your vue app, put your functions inside, then `inject` it into any component that needs it.

As it says in the comments, don't use jquery with Vue. Your event handler should be in the `methods` of the component that contains the button.